# MYSQL sort words in field

Tags: mysql, sql

**Edit 1** the code is just an example, I do not have suburb data, my real data is inherited and messy and could be fixed by creating code out of the database or creating reference data.  The question should have been something like does anyone have a good cell sort function or other solution that can be reused?

Table

```
CREATE TABLE postcode (
`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`suburbs` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)  ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Insert

```
INSERT INTO  postcode (`suburbs`)
VALUES ( 'Zackville;Astor;Mary-town;Jackson' );
```

Want field to be sorted an result to be

> Astor;Jackson;Mary-town;Zackville

Comment: Why not use a foreign key instead?

Comment: Don't have another table with suburbs

Comment: :-) After a generic solution

Comment: That *is* the generic solution. It sounds like you're after a very specialized solution to support a problematic database structure rather than improving your database structure to support generic solutions.

Comment: I am looking for a generic solution to sorting words in a field, I do not know if that is specialized or not.

Comment: The generic solution is as follows. Either 1. fix your schema, or 2. stop using an RDBMS.

Comment: Problem is not with schema, this is how the data comes. 2 may be correct.

Comment: Even if the data comes in such a format, you can preprocess it before inserting into the database so that you have one row for each suburb. When `SELECT`ing, you can sort them any way you want.

Comment: Thank Tsnorri, you are right but the example in my question is just an example, the real data (is aready in) needs a lot of work and I was hoping there was nice sort function out there (would put that in the question next time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All comments have **very valid** points and you **should** try to avoid working with delimited values in RDBMS.

That being said, if you're stuck with the existing database and you for some reason want to do it on the database level rather than with client code you can leverage tally(number) table and [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to split delimited values into rows, then [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to pivot data back in the ordered manner.

One of the several ways to create  a tally table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tally (n int not null primary key);
INSERT INTO tally (n)
SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
 FROM 
(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
ORDER BY n
```

*Number of rows in the tally table should be greater or equal to the maximum possible number of delimited values.*

Now to resort delimited values:

```sql
UPDATE postcode p JOIN
(
  SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(suburbs ORDER BY suburbs SEPARATOR ';') suburbs
    FROM
  (
    SELECT t.id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.suburbs, ';', n.n), ';', -1) suburbs
      FROM postcode t CROSS JOIN tally n
     WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.suburbs) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.suburbs, ';', '')))
  ) q
   GROUP BY id
) s 
    ON p.id = s.id
   SET p.suburbs = s.suburbs;
```

Output:

```
| ID |                           SUBURBS |
|----|-----------------------------------|
|  1 | Astor;Jackson;Mary-town;Zackville |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bde39/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks Peter, agree about avoiding delimited values. Tested your code on a few thousand records and it worked, I only added    `SET p.suburbs = TRIM(LEADING ';' FROM s.suburbs);` to trim the leading delimited that comes up on some records.

Comment: Just to be clear, Peter's answer is correct without using the trim(leading and was only needed for my test as I had not cleaned up all the delimiters (white space) in the test data. Thanks again Peter.